# JLabel not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a JLabel with an ImageIcon that isn't showing.

```
public class Lockscreen extends JFrame {
    JPanel layer;
    JButton signin;
    ImageIcon heartlock;
    String heartlockpath;
    JLabel heartlockdisplay;
    String arrowpath;

    public Lockscreen(){

        super("Startseite");
        setSize(700, 400);
        setLocation(100, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        arrowpath = "C:\\Users\\saydanan\\Pictures\\FürMyDiary\\Right_Arrow.png";
        signin = new JButton();
        signin.setSize(19, 12);
        signin.setIcon(new ImageIcon(arrowpath));
        signin.setLocation(250, 500);

        heartlockpath = "C:\\Users\\saydananPicturesFürMyDiary\\082326-green-jelly-icon-business-lock-heart.png";
        heartlock = new ImageIcon(heartlockpath);
        heartlockdisplay = new JLabel();
        heartlockdisplay.setIcon(heartlock);
        heartlockdisplay.setLocation(250, 250);
        heartlockdisplay.setSize(heartlock.getIconWidth(), heartlock.getIconHeight());
        heartlockdisplay.setVisible(true);


        layer = new JPanel();
        layer.setBackground(Color.black);
        /*layer.setLayout(...);*/
        addEverything(layer);
        getContentPane().add(layer);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addEverything(JPanel panel){
       panel.add(signin);
       panel.add(heartlockdisplay);
       panel.repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add all components to the contentpane instead (`getContentPane().add(..)`). If that works, then set some basic settings to `layer`, like position and size (especially if you don't use a layout manager for it).

Comment: It unfortunately didn´t work, sorry ^^;

Comment: Works fine for me. Only thing I can guess either you paths are wrong (have you checked to see if the ImageIcon is null), or you are simple forgetting a `main` method (if _"isn't showing"_ simply means the frame isn't showing :-).

Comment: Or like Tom mentioned, the position of the image. I don't have experience with JFrame, but try to bring the object to front.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! It works!! Oh my god, I love you guys, thank you so much!!! Now all I need to do is to position them.. peeskillet, you were right about the paths. One of them (the one of heartlockdisplay) was nonsense. Thanks for showing me what I was blind for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add it, and then set it to be visible.

As in:

```
panel.add(heartlockdisplay);
heartlockdisplay.setVisible(true);
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn´t work. Thanks for investing a thought, though. ^^